# SetWindowsHookEx not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, callback, setwindowshookex, global-hotkey

I have tried to make a global mousehotkey with `SetWindowsHookEx()` so when I press the right mouse button it executes some code. My problem is that when the callback function gets executed, it gives me a weird number for the right button that keeps changing everytime the code gets executed.

```
private static IntPtr ButtonHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {

        int button = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            if (button == 0x02)
            {
                _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Test");
            }

        }

        return CallNextHookEx(MainWindow._hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

When I read lParam it gives me like a number around 600 and changes everytime the code gets executed even though it should be 0x2.
How can I fix this :P.

**EDIT**: It works perfectly when I do it with keys

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx) `lParam` contains a pointer to an `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` struct. [This struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970(v=vs.85).aspx) contains essentially the x- and y-coordinates of the mouse cursor. Why should it be `0x2`?

Comment: What kind of hook is this? A keyboard or mouse hook? How are you installing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x02` means `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, which should come from `wParam` rather `lParam`. The `lParam` means `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT`, which will frequently change as for containing `x- and y-coordinates of the cursor`. Just refer to `[MouseProc callback function][1]` and `[MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT structure][2]`

- [1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644988(v=vs.85).aspx
- [2] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644968(v=vs.85).aspx